# NetworkX: adjacency matrix does not correspond to graph

Tags: python, matrix, networkx, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

Say I have two options for generating the **Adjacency Matrix** of a network: `nx.adjacency_matrix()` and my own code. I wanted to test the correctness of my code and came up with some strange inequalities.

Example: a `3x3` lattice network.

```
import networkx as nx
N=3
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = dict( ((i,j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
inds=labels.keys()
vals=labels.values()
inds.sort()
vals.sort()
pos2=dict(zip(vals,inds))
plt.figure()
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos2, with_labels=True, node_size = 200)
```

This is the visualization:
[image]

The adjacency matrix with `nx.adjacency_matrix()`:

```
B=nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
B1=B.todense()

[[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]]
```

According to it, node `0` (entire 1st row and entire 1st column) is connected to nodes `5` and `8`. But if you look at the image above this is wrong, as it connects to nodes `1` and `3`.

Now my code (to be run in in the same script as the above):

```
import numpy
import math

P=3

def nodes_connected(i, j):
     try: 
        if i in G.neighbors(j):
            return 1
     except nx.NetworkXError:
        return False          

A=numpy.zeros((P*P,P*P))

for i in range(0,P*P,1):
    for j in range(0,P*P,1):

        if i not in G.nodes():
            A[i][:]=0
            A[:][i]=0
        elif i in G.nodes():
            A[i][j]=nodes_connected(i,j)
                A[j][i]=A[i][j]

for i in range(0,P*P,1):
    for j in range(0,P*P,1):
            if math.isnan(A[i][j]):
                A[i][j]=0 

print(A)
```

This yields:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

which says that node `0` is connected to nodes `1` and `3`. **Why does such difference exist? What is wrong in this situation?**

Comment: not 100% sure, but related to the answer below, where you use `dict` above, you should change to using `collections.OrderedDict`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Networkx doesn't know what order you want the nodes to be in.

Here is how to call it: `adjacency_matrix(G, nodelist=None, weight='weight')`.

If you want a specific order, set nodelist to be a list in that order.
So for example `adjacency_matrix(G, nodelist=range(9))` should get what you want.

Why is this?  Well, because a graph can have just about anything as its nodes (anything hashable).  One of your nodes could have been `"parrot"` or `(1,2)`.  So it stores the nodes as keys in a dict, rather than assuming it's the non-negative integers starting at 0.  Dict keys [have an arbitrary order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary).

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution, if your nodes have some logical ordering as is the case if you generate a graph using `G=nx.grid_2d_graph(3,3)` (which returns tupples from (0,0) to (2,2), or in your example would be to use:

```
adjacency_matrix(G,nodelist=sorted(G.nodes()))
```

This sorts the returned list of nodes of G and passes it as the nodelist